# Linux shared memory segfault

Tags: c, linux, gdb, shared-memory

I have been having difficulties getting a useable shared memory region in a sample C program (RHEL 6). It should be quite basic so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but when I allocate the memory region it appears to be accessible initially. However, when I return from an initialization function the memory region is no longer accessible and I get a segfault when I try to access the memory region.

I have tried running it through GDB and all I see is a segfault on the line where I try to do this memcpy:

```
memcpy(ptr, &x, sizeof(x));
```

It's probably something minor that I just cannot see for some reason! Thanks.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>


void* shared_mem[2];

int init(int *memAddress);

int main() {

  if(init((int*)&shared_mem[0]) < 0) {
    printf("Error initializing, exiting\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  int *ptr=shared_mem[0];

  int x=278;
  memcpy(ptr, &x, sizeof(x));
  printf("data written to memAddress: %d\n", shared_mem[0]);

}

// Initialize shared memory region and insert test data
int init(int *memAddress) {
    key_t key = 234324;
    int size = sizeof(int);
    static const unsigned int flags = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP |
                                       S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH | IPC_CREAT;
    int id = shmget(key, size, flags);
    if (id < 0)
    {
        return(-3);
    }
    *memAddress = shmat(id,0,0);
    if ((int)memAddress == -1)
    {
        return(-4);
    }

    int z=123;
    memcpy(memAddress, &z, sizeof(z));
    printf("data written to memAddress: %d\n", memAddress[0]);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you assume you can freely mix pointers and `int`s. That would be a very wrong assumption. Rewrite to remove **all** casts and compile with -Wall -Werror.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something is completely wrong here and it begins with the following line:

```
int init(int *memAddress)
```

You pass a pointer to `shared_mem` to the function "init". Therefore `memAddress` will point to the 8- or 16-byte (depending on the CPU type) array `shared_mem`.

```
*memAddress = shmat(id,0,0);
```

If `sizeof(void *) == sizeof(int)` this would work however then you'd have to do other pointer casts. `shared_mem[0]` will contain a pointer to the memory, casted to `int`.

If `sizeof(void *) != sizeof(int)` you'll already have problems here.

```
(int)memAddress == -1
```

This will not work in any case:

`(int)memAddress` is the address of the array `shared_mem` and not the value returned by `shmat`.

```
memcpy(memAddress, &z, sizeof(z));
```

This will write the value `123` into `shared_mem[0]`. Therefore the following instruction:

```
memcpy(ptr, &x, sizeof(x));
```

... will be equal to:

```
memcpy((void *)123, &x, sizeof(x));
```

... which will cause the error.

The correct function would look like this:

```
int init(void **memAddress) {     // void **
    ...
    *memAddress = shmat(id,0,0);  // This was correct!
    if ((int)(*memAddress) == -1) // Note the "*"
        ...
    memcpy(*memAddress, &z, sizeof(z)); // Note the "*"
}
```

Comment: Yep that's pretty much what I said - the declaration of the init function needs to use `**memaddress`

Answer (score 2):

Your init function isn't modifiying shared_mem with the allocated memory address - the parameter to init() needs to be declared as `int **memaddress` for example look at your line `*memaddress=shmget(...)` with parameter defined as `int *memaddress` this is storing the result of shmget as an integer, that isn't right. You need to check all the related uses of memaddress are correct. You can check this in gdb, look at the result of shmget, make sure that is being stored in shared_mem[0].

Comment: The init function is meant to return error codes, not the memory address. The variable shared_mem[0] is passed by reference so it should contain the pointer to the shared memory when the function completes. The problem I am having is that I cannot access this memory outside the init function. I am not getting any error codes from the shmget and shmat system calls either. I will take a look again in gdb and see if memaddress is somehow being set wrong.

Comment: Yeah, when I said return, I meant it isn't setting the shared_mem variable correctly.